# “[Informatica][ODBC Oracle wire Protocol driver] number contains an invalid character

Tags: odbc, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

After I asked my DBA to make a copy of an Oracle schema for which I had already an ODBC connection on Informatica Server side, I got the following [image: error] :

I was thinking it was due the way my DBA created the copy, but unfortunately that is not the case, has the DBA has made more then a schema copy and this error show-up only for a specific schema

The really strange thing is that:

- Protocol used is the same : oracle Wire Protocol driver
- Database type is the same: same version of Oracle
- Connection type is the same(64 bit)
- For another copy from the same schema the ODBC before was working

But for the Staging and Mart the connection is working indeed as you can see from next image [connection work fine for another type of schema that is same as the other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVWf3.png)

it is really strange as I am not making directly the copies but as already wrote the ODBC connetcion work fine for the copies of other 2 schemas.

To add some more information for the same schema on which I have this issue, when I connect to it the first time from  Oracle SQL Developer, I got the following: (I cannot add another image yet):

*An error was encoutered performing the requested operation:

Exhausted Resultset

Vendor code 17011*

So I suspected It has to be with Informatica driver.
(So far I resolved asking to get make another copy of the schema, but from tejh DBA there was nothing made different)

As I already checked it is pretty general one from Oracle engine.

, nevertheless I can work with it from SQL Developer.

Comment: Check this: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000037530

Comment: @cha unfortunately I know already that article. I need to point it out that it refer to a MS SQL Server(so different port, different SID and so on). Also as it say in the article I checked teh  odbc.ini and my it is ok,moreover why it should be set in a wrong way if I have already other 2 schemas in the same Database for which the ODBC is perfectly working. I thinking about an encoding problem that come by some conflict with Oracle Server version, but I am not in charge of that in the company where I work

Comment: I found the solution, oracle engine was throwing the error: SP2-0575: Oracle SQL function not on SQL92 entry level. Obviously, the ODBC connection here has a problem to process the message. Sqldeveloper or other tools ignore the message.